# Is it possible to show hollow candle in Candlestick jfreechart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Most of financial chart libraries use some rules for coloring the candles:

1. if `close >= open`, then candle is `hollow` (not filled)
2. if `close < open`, then candle is `filled`
3. if `previous close <= close`, then candle is `green`
4. if `previous close > close`, then candle is `red`

jFreeChart seems to have own rules for coloring and it's possible to change them. By default the chart looks something like this (some colors has been changed):

[image: candlestick chart jfreechart]

So as you see, it is possible to change the colors of candles, background, plot borders etc.

I'd like to implement rules 1 and 2 (above) to the chart. Is it possible?

**The result should be like this:**

[image: jfreechart ohlc candlestick]

This is my current CandlestickRenderer used in the example:

```
public class CandlestickRenderer extends org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.CandlestickRenderer {

    public CandlestickRenderer() {
        setDrawVolume(false);
    }

    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(int series, int item) {
        OHLCDataset highLowData = (OHLCDataset)getPlot().getDataset(series);
        Number curClose = highLowData.getClose(series, item);
        Number prevClose = highLowData.getClose(series, item>0 ? item-1 : 0);
        if (prevClose.doubleValue() <=  curClose.doubleValue()) {
            return getUpPaint();
        }
        else {
            return getDownPaint();
        }
    }   
}
```

### Update 1

It seems it can be done just by setting `up paint` to `black` and draw `item pant` unchanged with colors.

```
public class CandlestickRenderer extends org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.CandlestickRenderer {

    public CandlestickRenderer() {
        setDrawVolume(false);
        setUseOutlinePaint(false);
        setUpPaint(Color.BLACK); // <-- rule 1. (plot is also black so it looks not filled)
    }

    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(int series, int item) {
        OHLCDataset highLowData = (OHLCDataset) getPlot().getDataset(series);
        Number curClose = highLowData.getClose(series, item);
        Number prevClose = highLowData.getClose(series, item>0 ? item-1 : 0);

        if (prevClose.doubleValue() <=  curClose.doubleValue()) {
            return Color.GREEN; // <-- rule 3.
        } else {
            return Color.RED; // <-- rule 4.
        }
    }

}
```

But the main question lasts:

- What does it mean `down (downPaint)` and `up (upPaint)` according jFreeChart? Does it compare `prev. close vs. close` values or `open vs. close`?
- Where in the source of jFreeChart can I find the part where `upPaint` & `downPaint` are used?

This is the strange result now:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it. Here is the complete own renderer:

```
public class CandlestickRenderer extends org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.CandlestickRenderer {

    private final Paint colorRaising = Color.GREEN;
    private final Paint colorFalling = Color.RED;
    private final Paint colorUnknown = Color.GRAY;
    private final Paint colorTransparent = Color.BLACK;

    public CandlestickRenderer() {
        setDrawVolume(false);
        setUpPaint(colorUnknown); // use unknown color if error
        setDownPaint(colorUnknown); // use unknown color if error
    }


    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(int series, int item) {
        OHLCDataset highLowData = (OHLCDataset) getPlot().getDataset(series);
        Number curClose = highLowData.getClose(series, item);
        Number prevClose = highLowData.getClose(series, item>0 ? item-1 : 0);

        if (prevClose.doubleValue() <=  curClose.doubleValue()) {
            return Color.GREEN;
        } else {
            return Color.RED;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void drawItem(Graphics2D g2, XYItemRendererState state,
            Rectangle2D dataArea, PlotRenderingInfo info, XYPlot plot,
            ValueAxis domainAxis, ValueAxis rangeAxis, XYDataset dataset,
            int series, int item, CrosshairState crosshairState, int pass) {

        OHLCDataset highLowData = (OHLCDataset) dataset;
        double yOpen = highLowData.getOpenValue(series, item);
        double yClose = highLowData.getCloseValue(series, item);        

        // set color for filled candle
        if (yClose >= yOpen) {
            setUpPaint(colorRaising);
            setDownPaint(colorFalling);
        }

        // set color for hollow (not filled) candle
        else {
            setUpPaint(colorTransparent);
            setDownPaint(colorTransparent);
        }

        // call parent method
        super.drawItem(g2, state, dataArea, info, plot, domainAxis, rangeAxis, dataset, series, item, crosshairState, pass);
    }   

}
```

And resulting chart:

[image]

Don't hesitate to contact me if you'll want all the example code.